# Selecting An Array of Triggers and using data from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, keypress

I am trying to create an easy way for my users to select the trigger key that makes the code work altogether. I have this so far.

```
var triggers = {space:"32",enter:"13",tab:"9"};
var triggerKeys = ["space","enter"];

$('input').on('keypress',function(event) {
 var unicode= event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
   if(unicode === triggers[triggerKeys]) {
       //code initiation here
   }
```

Though of course this doesn't work. Any ideas on how I could possibly make it so in the array of `triggerKeys` the code is initiated, as well if they have more than one triggerKeys?

Code works for just one Trigger. Should I for loop the triggerKeys for more than one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're after, but I'd do something like this :

```
$('input').on('keypress',function(e) {
    switch (e.which) {
        case 32: //space
            console.log('space');
            break;
        case 13: //enter
            console.log('enter');
            break;
        case 9: //tab
            console.log('tab');
    }
});
```

as using an array as a key for another array never seems to work for me ?

If you are just trying to check if a key exists in an array, store the keycodes :

```
var triggerKeys = [32, 13, 9];

$('input').on('keypress',function(e) {
    if ( $.inArray(e.which, triggerKeys) != -1 ) {
       // one of the triggerkeys was pressed
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**

Here's another example with the map you're using, and checking if a trigger key was pressed :

```
var triggerKeys = ["space","enter", "tab"];
var triggers    = {space: 32, enter: 13, tab: 9};

$('input').on('keypress',function(e) {
    var arr = $.map(triggerKeys, function(el, i) {return triggers[el];});
    if ( $.inArray( e.which, arr ) != -1 ) {
        console.log('trigger key pressed')
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Hf6/1/)

Comment: please take a look here Adeneo http://jsbin.com/eqoyag/1/edit as this is what is happening, and I need it this way to make it easier for my users as they are far from even being close to a newb, they have no idea what charCodes are

Comment: If your users can select things like "space" and "enter", you need a map, as in an object, to match those strings to keycodes, as javascript doesn't understand "enter". This is basically what you're already doing, so just apply that to the above answer. I'll add an example ?

Comment: This works wonderfully! I've never used the .map() function yet. el is to element, and i is to index. I just like learning the code, ;) so we map the TriggerKeys turning them into a new array or object. Then we return the triggers to the corresponding triggerKey?

Comment: `$.map` can be used on objects as well as elements, just like `$.each`, but note that the order of `i` and `el` is opposite (and there is no `this`), and I should really have used `value` / `key` and not `el` / `i` as that is somewhat misleading, as it's not really elements being mapped but keys and values, but I guess old habits die hard!

Comment: lol. no its fine, I read up a little on the .map() and i understood what the `el`/ `i` was being used for. Thanks though man! I appreciate it. I understand there was probably an easier way, but when you are trying to make something as simple as possible this would be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to run some code based on the value of the variable `unicode` then it suffices to just check for the presence of a value in a set.

A simple way is to use an array for your set

```
var triggerKeys = [32, 13];
```

then check as follows:

```
if (triggerKeys.indexOf(unicode) >= 0) {
    // ...
}
```

but according to [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) `indexOf` might not be in all browsers.

Alternatively you simulate a set with :

```
var triggerKeys = {32: true, 13: true};
```

and just say

```
if (unicode in triggerKeys) {
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT**

To increase readability of your code, you can continue with your approach of defining key names and key codes:

```
var triggers = {space: 32, enter: 13, tab: 9};
var triggerKeys = ["space", "enter"];
```

The actual trigger key codes would then be computed from the triggers

```
var triggers = {space:"32",enter:"13",tab:"9"};
var triggerKeys = ["space", "enter"];
var triggerKeyCodes = {};

for (var i = 0; i < triggerKeys.length; i += 1) {
    triggerKeyCodes[triggers[triggerKeys[i]]] = true;
}
```

This makes the `triggerKeyCodes` object look like `{32:true, 13:true}`. Then you can write:

```
if (unicode in triggerKeyCodes) {
    // ...
}
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/eqoyag/5/edit

Since you are using jQuery already, adeneo's answer is better.  The upcoming version of JavaScript will have some nice features (comprehensions, maps, etc.), that will make the raw-JavaScript version cleaner.

Comment: Please take a look here http://jsbin.com/eqoyag/1/edit  as my users I deal with don't know the value of charcodes, so I figured an easier way would be to assign enter space tab and so forth.